# Elasticsearch NEST fluent DSL Field name .Suffix causes syntax error

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Using NEST DSL to filter on the "keyword" suffix of the FileLogNum field.

```cs
public class ElasticSearchAttachment
{
    public string FileLogNum { get; set; }
}
```

which elasticsearch returns as

```
{"mappings": {"properties":"fileLogNum":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}
```

Here is my fluent dsl query

```cs
var results = elasticClient.Search<ElasticSearchAttachment>(search => search
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Filter(fl => fl
                .Term(t => t.FileLogNum.Suffix("keyword"), "19-113257")
            )
        )
    )
```

with intellisense generating an error on "FileLogNum.Suffix" of "CS1061: TermQueryDesciptor does not contain a definition for 'FileLogNum' ..."

No where else do I see anyone mentioning not being able to use .Suffix in this situation.

NEST and Elasticsearch dotnet are on version 7.10.0.

Sure there is something simple I am missing, but I am not seeing it. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh. PEBCAK. Never put in the `using Nest;` statement. There goes 4 hours of my life.